# Jquery Load Not Loading after going to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html page where a JQuery Loads a page into a div on click. I can click on it and it goes to page 2 and it works. I have the same link that goes back to page 1 and it will load the html in page 1, but if I click back to page 2 it will not load. So pretty much I cannot go back and forth on loading a div from Jquery. I have search and seen something on using live() but can't seem to get anything to work. Any Suggestions?

My Jquery Function to load the div from another page.

```
<script>
function changepage(page) {
    $(function(){
        $('#maincontent').load('index.php?p='+page);
        return false;
    });
}
</script>
```

HTML To load the page 2:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changepage('page2');">Page 2</a>
```

HTML To load back to page 2

```
<a href="#" onclick="changepage('page1');">Page 1</a>
```

EDIT:
Entire Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>My Page</title>


</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="maincontent">

            <a href="#" onclick="changepage('page2');">Page 2</a>


                </div>
                <!-- /.maincontent -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->


<script>
function changepage(page) {
    $(function(){
        $('#maincontent').load('subpage.php?p='+page);
        return false;
    });
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That looks correct, is jQuery included on both of your HTML pages?

Comment: Yes, It's placed on both pages

Comment: Alright, can you show us the html for both the pages? More than just the anchor tags.

Comment: I edited it and added the main page. The subpages just contain links to each other page.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery linked in the HTML there. That needs to be linked to for the custom jQuery to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with **tokyovariable**. you need to link jquery before using it in function. Try adding 

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`
before script with `changepage` function.
 Also make sure jquery is loaded before `changepage` function is called. Try 
`function changepage(page) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#maincontent').load('index.php?p='+page);
        return false;
    });
}`

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me. There is an original page with jQuery, and a div that is dynamically changing. There is only one full page load in this action. So putting jQUery in the child page doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is jQuery linked to on that page?

Comment: Yes, The JQuery function is on both pages. I have tired combonations on placing it in the head, body, on both pages, est.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't think you've given us enough information here. The above code looks fine. Is input.php working correctly? What happens when you call:

```
http://[domain]/index.php?p=page1
http://[domain]/index.php?p=page2
```

From a browser? Does it output a whole page, or just #maincontent? It's kind of weird, does the index page output a single div, or are you stuffing a whole html page inside another one? Sound like it could be the output from index.php, which would normally be the landing page of your site, so why are you stuffing the whole landing page inside a div?

Comment: The http://[domain]/index.php?p=page1 and page2 works just fine. It only displays the #maincontent. I have a case/switch in the index.php page where it calls the p which are the subpages and if nothing is called it loads the whole page with page1 in the main content.